# tipa partially incompatible with leipzig?

Tags: typography, linguistics, tipa, leipzig

I'm using tipa to, well, use the IPA in my thesis. If I load leipzig, some of the inputs defined in tipa no longer work, for example:

`\textipa{\:r}`, which should produce "ɽ" ([this symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_retroflex_flap)), produces " r" as soon as I load leipzig.

Same with `\textipa{\;G}`, which should produce "ɢ" ([this symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_uvular_plosive)), but produces "ɣ" ([this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_velar_fricative)) preceded by a space instead, which would regularly be produced by `\textipa{ G}`.

It seems that `\:` and `\;` get ignored or are compiled as spaces.

Any help for a tex beginner? Thank you. ❤

Edit: Thank you everyone for your help. Meow.

Comment: leipzip loads (through various other packages) amsmath, and that redefines `\:` again. If you don't need the command in math, load tipa later. Safer would be to avoid the redefinition (option "safe") and to use the alternative input described in the tipa documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to load `tipa` after `leipzig`. But this way you lose the commands `\|`, `\:`, `\;`, `\!` and `\*` with their usual meaning.

Nothing to worry about very much, as they are mostly used in math and if you don't have math in your document you should be pretty safe.

The following code saves the meaning of the five commands after loadig `leipzig`. Then also after loading `tipa`. Finally, we locally change the commands to their `tipa` meaning when `\textipa` or `IPA` is processed and restore their standard meaning for the document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{leipzig}
\usepackage{tipa}

\begin{document}

\textipa{\:r \;G \*f \!b \|[t}

\end{document}
```

[image]

There is a (not so elegant) way to keep everything with its standard meaning:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{leipzig}

\NewCommandCopy{\amsmathbar}{\|}
\NewCommandCopy{\amsmathcolon}{\:}
\NewCommandCopy{\amsmathsemicolon}{\;}
\NewCommandCopy{\amsmathbang}{\!}
\NewCommandCopy{\amsmathstar}{\*}

\usepackage{tipa}

\NewCommandCopy{\tipabar}{\|}
\NewCommandCopy{\tipacolon}{\:}
\NewCommandCopy{\tipasemicolon}{\;}
\NewCommandCopy{\tipabang}{\!}
\NewCommandCopy{\tipastar}{\*}

\AddToHook{cmd/tipaencoding/before}{%
  \RenewCommandCopy{\|}{\tipabar}%
  \RenewCommandCopy{\:}{\tipacolon}%
  \RenewCommandCopy{\;}{\tipasemicolon}%
  \RenewCommandCopy{\!}{\tipabang}%
  \RenewCommandCopy{\*}{\tipastar}%
}
\RenewCommandCopy{\|}{\amsmathbar}
\RenewCommandCopy{\:}{\amsmathcolon}
\RenewCommandCopy{\;}{\amsmathsemicolon}
\RenewCommandCopy{\!}{\amsmathbang}
\RenewCommandCopy{\*}{\amsmathstar}

\begin{document}

\textipa{\:r \;G \*f \!b \|[t}

a\:b\;c\!d$\*\|$

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can avoid that horrible mess in your document by writing your own package, let's call it `leipzig-tipa.sty`

```
\ProvidesPackage{leipzig-tipa}
\RequirePackage{leipzig}

\NewCommandCopy{\amsmathbar}{\|}
\NewCommandCopy{\amsmathcolon}{\:}
\NewCommandCopy{\amsmathsemicolon}{\;}
\NewCommandCopy{\amsmathbang}{\!}
\NewCommandCopy{\amsmathstar}{\*}

\RequirePackage{tipa}

\NewCommandCopy{\tipabar}{\|}
\NewCommandCopy{\tipacolon}{\:}
\NewCommandCopy{\tipasemicolon}{\;}
\NewCommandCopy{\tipabang}{\!}
\NewCommandCopy{\tipastar}{\*}

\AddToHook{cmd/tipaencoding/before}{%
  \RenewCommandCopy{\|}{\tipabar}%
  \RenewCommandCopy{\:}{\tipacolon}%
  \RenewCommandCopy{\;}{\tipasemicolon}%
  \RenewCommandCopy{\!}{\tipabang}%
  \RenewCommandCopy{\*}{\tipastar}%
}
\RenewCommandCopy{\|}{\amsmathbar}
\RenewCommandCopy{\:}{\amsmathcolon}
\RenewCommandCopy{\;}{\amsmathsemicolon}
\RenewCommandCopy{\!}{\amsmathbang}
\RenewCommandCopy{\*}{\amsmathstar}

\endinput
```

Place the created file in directory searched by TeX and your document can become

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{leipzig-tipa}

\begin{document}

\textipa{\:r \;G \*f \!b \|[t}

\end{document}
```